# Http request is failing on Android 9, but works on earlier versions on android

Tags: android, http, flutter

I'm trying to make http request on android 9, but it fails. For other versions of android it works fine, the issue is only related with android 9, I have also tried to add android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" attribute to android manifest, but it doesn't help.

Comment: `but it fails` -> how so? care to provide, you know, *any* detail? :)

Comment: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-28#framework-security-changes -- use network security configuration, not the deprecated `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` attribute.